# When run the Connect to Oracle Database using jybot getting the error cx_Oracle is not found

Tags: robotframework

I tried to run the Query from Oracle Database using `jybot` option as i have some java custom code, that need in my test script along with query from oracle database.

I got the error `cx_Oracle is not found`.

When run the same using pybot (removed the java custom code) then i didn't get any errors.

If i run the java custom code alone using jybot then also no errors.

**Steps i followed to install Database Library are as follows:**

*Install Visual C++ Compiler*

1. Download and Install VCForPython27.msi (If not have the executable file, please check Important URLs section for link to download)
2. Set Environment Variables ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN if not setup already.

*Install Database Library*

Open the command prompt and run the following command

> pip install robotframework-databaselibrary

*Install cx_Oracle*

Open the command prompt and run the following command

> pip install cx_Oracle

**Connect to Oracle Database Code:**

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    cx_Oracle    '${Username}/${Password}@${Host}:${Port}/${DatabaseName}'

@{Numbers}    Query    SELECT NUMBER_V from MASTER_DB WHERE STATUS_V='F' and ROWNUM <= 10

Log    ${Numbers[0]}
```

Any one, please help me how to run the query from oracle database using jybot.

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: looks like a configuration problem of jybot. It is not able to see the oracle instance installed by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_Oracle can't be sucessfully used under the jybot

Here is my solution:

1. Install [DatabaseLibrary](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.6/DatabaseLibrary.html) module by

   ```
   pip install robotframework-databaselibrary
   ```
2. Install [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) module by

   ```
   pip install JayDeBeApi
   ```

   - *now you can put these libraries anywhere you like - just copy them from Python\Lib\site-packages*
3. And here is going the trick!
   The DatabaseLibrary usage have following sample for jaydebeapi connection:

   ```
   Connect To Database Using Custom Params | JayDeBeApi | 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'my_db_test', 'system', 's3cr3t'
   ```

However this is **wrong**! You have to use the brackets over the username-pass pair! Like this:

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params | JayDeBeApi | 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'my_db_test', ['system', 's3cr3t']
```

And please do not forget to use URL connection instead of my_db_test! It should be like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/my_db_test
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for reply, is above solution works for both pybot and jybot?

Comment: yes. tests in our company are starting from the Java version of the RF, so i had to do that trick above